# How to locate the correct image path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, ipad

I save my images in the folder "pic" (an example of a full path for an image: `/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2526EA68-229D-40BC-BB57-56E46EB55691/Documents/pic/1.jpg`).

The "Document" path is got by calling:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

So the path is definitely correct . But when I do:

```
 [tempImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImagePath]]
```

It seems that the image is not found, because the image is not shown. I want to know the reason for this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: The variable fullImagePath is one NSString with image name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`imageNamed` only works for images in the main bundle, not in subdirectories.

Use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
```

instead.